# Create a new reference to instantiated class in Python

Tags: python

I have a class property that contains a class reference as such

```
class UserEnvironment(object):
    _user = None

    def __init__(self, session_id):
         self._user = User(session_id)

    def create_user(self):
         # copy self._user modify the copy and return it without modifying original object.
```

what I need to do is take self._user and create a new instance from it, then return the reference without modifying the original object. How can I do this?

Comment: you need the `copy` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't define `_user` as a class member. Remove the statement or `_user` will be the same for all class instances. Probably not what you want.

Then, to "clone" the user, just use `copy.deepcopy` like this;

import copy

```
class UserEnvironment(object):

    def __init__(self, session_id):
         self._user = User(session_id)

    def create_user(self):
         # copy self._user modify the copy and return it without modifying original object.
         return copy.deepcopy(self._user)
```

note that `copy.deepcopy` clones *all* members recursively, which may be a problem if your class references itself or a big dataset that never changes.

Depending on the case, you could use `copy.copy`, or just create your own custom `clone` method for instance like this:

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self, session_id):
       self.__session_id = session_id
       self.__random = random.random()

   def clone(self):
       u = User(self.__session_id)
       # overwrite the random field by ours
       u.__random = self.__random
       return u
```

Comment: As noted in `copy` documentation, `deepcopy` can have the problem of "copying too much": https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: @Ibolla. and `copy.copy` not enough :) Well, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's the problem with using the `copy` module. I don't see why it's needed, given that all the information to create `User` is readily available.

Comment: @Ibolla: you don't know that. Check my implementation of `User` class. `User` could have other data members, other methods modifying them. You cannot call all the methods called on the first object on the second object to reflect its state.

Comment: But in your last piece of code, your `clone` is exactly doing that: just creating a new `User` instance using the information readily available. See my proposed solution below: your `clone()` is the same as my `create_user()`. You also added a `__random` member, maybe in the attempt to make the instances "different", but there is no need, given that their `id()` will be different anyway.

Comment: not exactly: it has to call a constructor, but the next line isn't doable with the constructor (override random member with source object value) because `random` will be different each time. And it's better because the `User` object has the knowledge on how to clone itself. In your example you're implementing it in the `UserEnvironment` class, IMHO in the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html) module:

```
import copy

def create_user(self):
    user_copy = copy.deepcopy(self._user)
    # do something with it. or simply change assignment with `return`
    return user_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
    class UserEnvironment(object):
    _user = None

    def __init__(self, session_id):
        self.session_id = session_id
        self._user = self.create_user()

    def create_user(self):
        return User(self.session_id)
```

Just keep a reference to `session_id` and use it to create a new `User` when you need it.

Comment: This will lead to a recursion error since the User constructor calls create_user repeatedly.

Comment: @SonderingNarcissist no, it is not the same object: `User` vs `UserEnvironment`